# Best way to utilize cake

Tags: card-wars-kingdom

I've gotten a few different types of cake, and after hitting level 4, I've discovered that they can level up a card.  However, the only unused card I had was green and the game forced me to use 2 pink cake on it.  Thing is, I also had 2 blue cake and a green one.

So, what's the best way to level up cards?  Does pink cake work better on pink cards?  Should I use as many cake at a time as possible?  Is mixing different colors of cake ever a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three types of cakes for each faction: 
Slice, Single Layer, Double Layer.
What i have found so far is that the best way to actually level creatures is to use another creatures that you don't need from the same faction.

If you use a cake or creature from the same faction you get 1.5x the exp of leveling where if you level a nicelands creature using a swamp cake or creature you will get 1.0 the exp

So far i have found that the best way to level a creature to lvl 10 is to level it up to lvl 4 using same faction cakes and then one same faction creature that you don't need. If you play the game regularly its actually easier to get unneeded creatures by doing the dailies instead of wasting hearts or gems on cakes